# Denodo VQL, use union to add a record to view

Tags: union, denodo, vql

I'm trying to add a specific record to a view in VQL using UNION but it gives me an error saying **com.denodo.vdb.admin.model.vdbserverproxy.VDBServerProxyException: The field properties can only be specified for derived fields**. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
(SELECT x,x,x
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN c ON c.id = a.id
WHERE .....)
UNION
(SELECT  'y' 'y', 'y');
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid this behavior, you could build a SELECTION view on top of this UNION view and add there your descriptions and properties.